# Stack Exchange Fellowship Program: Looking for volunteers to review proposals

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Stack Exchange will be introducing a Fellowship Program awarding grants to students conducting independent research projects. Undergraduate Honors Theses, Independent Study Projects, Masters Theses, and Dissertations are eligible projects.

Prospective fellows will be asked to demonstrate a commitment to the discipline, approval or guidance of faculty adviser, two page proposal of the project, and intent to use their research to contribute to the relevant Stack Exchange community.

Before officially introducing the Fellowship Program and calling for applications, we need experienced community members to volunteer to review applicants' two page proposals and abstracts. We're ideally looking for people who are graduate/professional students or have advanced degrees in the subject, but relevant work experience is valuable too.

Stack Exchange Fellows will be in the following subjects:

- English
- [Statistics](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/stack-exchange-fellowship-and-grant-program-looking-for-reviewers-to-assess-thes)
- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/924/stack-exchange-fellowship-and-grant-program-looking-for-reviewers-to-assess-thes)
- [Linguistics](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175/stack-exchange-fellowship-and-grant-program-looking-for-reviewers-to-assess-thes)
- [Philosophy](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/stack-exchange-fellowship-and-grant-program-looking-for-reviewers-to-assess-thes)

Interested in being a reviewer? Respond here or email me at lauren@stackexchange.com.